# MySql Lock Tables Blocking Logic

Tags: mysql, locking

The [MySQL documentation (5.5) for Lock tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html) states:
[image]

Let's say that I'm trying to lock `table1` and `table2` in a single query, but `table2` is already locked. Will MySQL hold onto a lock on `table1` and block until it can lock `table2` or will it only hold onto a lock on `table1` when it can get a lock on both tables?

In case it matters, assume the InnoDB storage engine.

---

Update
I just found the following statement on the same page:

> When the session has gotten the WRITE lock and is waiting to get the lock for the next table in the lock table list, all other sessions wait for the WRITE lock to be released.

Is this confirming that MySQL will block whilst holding the lock on `table1`? If that is the case, is there a way to query MySQL such that it will immediately return with a failure rather than block if it fails to grab all of the table locks?

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use `LOCK TABLES` with InnoDB unless you have a very special need.

Instead, learn about "transactions" and use `BEGIN`...`COMMIT` to effect most "locking" needed.  See also `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE...`.

Comment: I already know about transactions. This question was specifically about locking tables. This is a special case.

Comment: OK.  You have to LOCK all tables at once.  The `LOCK TABLE` code depends on that for deadlock prevention, rather than having some complex code.